# Pre-seeding debconf doesn't impact install of libdvd-pkg

Tags: debconf

I'm raising this here as I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm just going crazy.  But when I'm installing a new Ubuntu Desktop I like to use chunks of copy&paste-able lines to get useful stuff installed really quick... e.g...

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get -y install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Which works fine.

But when it comes to libdvd-pkg, I just can't get it to shut up (I don't want to use 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive').  Here is what I've tried...

```
echo libdvd-pkg libdvd-pkg/first-install note | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo libdvd-pkg libdvd-pkg/post-invoke_hook-install boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get -y install libdvd-pkg
```

You always get this screen...

[image]

I've seen this happen on 12+ machines now, so it's not just a one off.

This is on Ubuntu 16.04 by the way.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong to try and silence this?

I've inspected the DEBIAN/templates file within the .deb package and can't find anything unusual.

Answer (score 3):

Install manually the first time, then use `debconf-get-selections | grep "^libdvd-pkg"` to see what debian confirm uses.  After that, put the result in a script and execute `debconf-set-selections` before installing the package.

1) Run deb-conf-get-selections on a installed machine:

```
#$ debconf-get-selections | grep "^libdvd-pkg"
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/build    boolean true
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/upgrade  note
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/post-invoke_hook-remove  boolean false
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/post-invoke_hook-install boolean true
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/first-install    note
```

2) Put these lines in a installer script, before installing:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Installing libdvd-pkg ... "

cat <<EndOfConfig | sudo debconf-set-selections
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/build    boolean true
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/upgrade  note
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/post-invoke_hook-remove  boolean false
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/post-invoke_hook-install boolean true
libdvd-pkg  libdvd-pkg/first-install    note
EndOfConfig

sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

Done!

You can do this in all packages who has dialogs and user interaction.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 22.04, this doesn't work - a popup is still displayed (I've double checked the debconf entries).

Answer (score 1):

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -yq install libdvd-pkg
sudo bash /usr/lib/libdvd-pkg/b-i_libdvdcss.sh
```